# grails how load external config file before config.groovy

Tags: grails, configuration

Grails app where based on my external properties file, I then want to load appropriate provider in the config.groovy (grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames). This means doing a check in config.groovy based on a property in the external config. Is there a way to load the external config before the config.groovy or other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just reading the properties file in the config.groovy for the one property I needed. Maybe not the best solution, but this worked.

```
Properties prop = new Properties()
try {
  File fileLoc=new File((grails.config.locations[0] as String).substring(5))
  prop.load(new FileInputStream(fileLoc))
  providerType = prop.getProperty("grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerType") ?:''
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Externalized Configs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized). Specially,

> Values that have the same name as previously defined values will
>   overwrite the existing values, and the pointed to configuration
>   sources are loaded in the order in which they are defined.

and **Config defaults** as

> The configuration values contained in the locations described by the
>   **grails.config.locations** property will override any values defined in
>   your application `Config.groovy` file which may not be what you want.
>   You may want to have a set of default values be be loaded that can be
>   overridden in either your application's `Config.groovy` file or in a
>   named config location. For this you can use the
>   **grails.config.defaults.locations** property.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more, in the external properties file I have: grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerType=saml then in the config.groovy I want to do if (grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerType=='saml' {grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['samlAuthProvider']} This allows the customer to say they want to use saml but then the code says which provider to use.